# Returning a 201 (Created) with location header in Vapor 3

Tags: vapor

I am trying to implement a REST-ful API using Vapor 3, and I'd prefer to use what seems like a fairly standard creation pattern in other web frameworks: I'd like the entity creation controllers to return a 201 `Created` response status, with a `Location` response header that contains the full URL of the newly-created resource.

All of the Vapor 3 documentation I can find shows a create pattern that instead returns a 200 `OK` status, and includes the full resource in the response body. But I can't find any examples that use a 201 response even though that tends to be the more standard REST-ful API approach in my experience.

I have found that I can manually create a 201 response in my controller, and I assume there's a way to set arbitrary headers in that response. If so, is there a convenient way of getting the full URL of the resource I've just created so that I can set a `Location` header in the response?

I'm sure there are ways I can "brute force" this to get what I want but I am hoping that Vapor defines an idiomatic way to do this, much like the Java and Rails frameworks I've used provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are manually creating a response, you are right, adding an arbitrary header is simple.

I assume you are following the standard CRUD route structure, so if you have a `User` model, you have the following routes:

- `POST /users`
- `GET /users/:user`
- `PATCH /users/:user`
- `DELETE /users/:user`

The important part here is that we know that the URL to get the user is the URL to create a user, plus the user's ID. If this is the case, we can create a location header like this:

```swift
user.save(on: req).map { user in
    let http = HTTPResponse(...)

    let location = req.http.url.path + "/" + user.id.description
    http.headers.replaceOrAdd(name: "Location", value: location)

    return Response(http: http, container: req)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping for something less manual, but I can certainly use this approach. I guess I've been spoiled a bit by Rails and its path/URI helpers that are automatically created for resource routes you define. This approach works though - And as long as I stick to pretty standard CRUD route structures and I don't need to replicate this logic in multiple places it should be fine.